# Hash value not injecting other variable's value in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable like below in powershell

```
 $children = @{'key'='value\\$child\\Parameters'}
```

Now consider the below:

```
$child = "hey"
$parent = "$child ho"

Write-Host $parent
```

This prints

```
hey ho
```

so basically the string `$parent` is able to use the string `$child` defined.
When expecting the same behavior from the value of the hashtable, this doesn't happen. For example:

```
$child = "hey"
$children = @{'key'='value\\$child\\Parameters'}

$children.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
$param = $_.Value
Write-Host $param
}
```

This prints

```
 value\\$child\\Parameters
```

instead of making use of `$child` and printing `value\\hey\\Parameters`
I thought it might be because of the type so I tried using `| Out-String` and  `|% ToString` with `$_.Value` to convert in to string but it still doesn't work.
Any way to make use of $_.Value and still have the $child value injected?

Apologies but my vocab is more java-like than powershell.

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted aka _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values) in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted aka _verbatim strings_). If the string value itself contains `"` chars., escape them as `\`"` or `""`, or use a double-quoted _here-string_.  See the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is with quotes. If you change the single quotes to double quotes you can see the interpolation will work as expected.

```
$child = "hey"
$children = @{"key"="value\\$child\\Parameters"}
```

Here is the relevant part from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) which explain this behaviour.

> ***Single-quoted strings***
>
> A string enclosed in single quotation marks is a verbatim string. The
> string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No
> substitution is performed.
>
> ***Double-quoted strings***
>
> A string enclosed in double quotation marks is an expandable string.
> Variable names preceded by a dollar sign (`$`) are replaced with the
> variable's value before the string is passed to the command for
> processing.